# How to save message file in RAW format

Tags: openstack-swift

One of our client does not know how to save/generate/produce/provide swift messages in its raw format via their swift alliance system, neither do i. By raw format i mean following format

```
{1:F21XXXXXXXXXXXX7108170239}{4:{177:1112071543}{451:0}}{1:F01XXXXXXXXXXXX7108170239}{2:O9502137111207XXXXXXXXXXXX54153885641112071537N}{4:
:20:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
:25:XXXXXXXXXX
:28C:00237/00001
:60F:C090513AUD1162994,30
:61:1112061207D110,00NCHKFDD388407       //071211WDM9103
291111 GUJ
:61:1112061207D200,00NCHK3927611471      //071211WDM9104
090911 KAR
:62F:C090513AUD1610881,52
:64:C090513AUD1610881,52
-}{5:{CHK:XXXXXXXXXXXX}}{S:{COP:S}}
```

Is there any way/interface to integrate with SWIFT and extract these files Or is there any possibility to schedule SWIFT to generate these files Or even manual steps to do it?

**Edit 1**

Messages are saved by creating a profile from the application and setting connection type to "File Transfer". It will then keep generating files in ISO format to a shared location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages are saved by creating a profile from the application and setting connection type to "File Transfer". It will then keep generating files in ISO format to a shared location.

Answer (score 0):

to get output file from swift you need to configure message partner CBSOUT

to do so do the following

enter to swift application SAE or SAA with super user.

click on
Application interface.
from the list right click on 
CBSOUT and then enable

to configure CBSOUT double click on it.

Data format :select RJE

output path name : put the folder you want to store the files

output the extension : put the file extension example :out or txt.

session initiation select Auto.

number of message =1

finish.

good lucky.

byeeeeeee